# Multiple Wordpress Blogs on a Domain

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have a custom PHP/MySQL e-commerce site at domain.com.

I have multiple Wordpress blogs that I would like to have the following URL structure:

- domain.com/blog-one/
- domain.com/blog-two/
- domain.com/blog-three/
- domain.com/blog-four/

Each of the these blogs are completely independent of the others. Each have their own theme, content, database, etc...

Is this possible?

Even if it is possible, am I asking for potential issues having these set up as sub-folders and not sub-domains?

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fine. I currently have two Wordpress blogs in two different folders.

Comment: So how do you set that up?  Dump all the WP files into the sub-folder set the WP and Site URL to domain.com/blog-# for each blog? Does this increase the security risks for the entire domain by using this configuration?

Comment: Basically yes, make sure you are using the URL as the main URL for the site or you will run into big problems.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  "URL as the main URL for the site".  Can you give me an example?  Thanks

Comment: You need to install WP in the directory and then create different databases for each installation. You should be able to upload the files to the directory and the WP installation will begin. Have you tried anything yet? Where are you getting stuck at. I have included a link below about Installing Multiple Blogs, hope this helps.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.  I want to make sure it is possible before I attempt it.  I don't want to screw up the e-commere part of the site.

Comment: It's possible, might need to tweak it to work. My suggestion is to run a local copy of the site and test before running on a production site.

Comment: Yes, I would test in a staging area.  I didn't want to waste my time setting everything up if it is possible.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use WPMU set to a folder structure? The ecommerce site can be the default 'blog' at the root and the other blogs would have the structure you want from above. Also you would have a mush easier time maintianing each since they would share the same base code, plugins, etc, while having separate themes and content for each one.

[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: Does anything in your answer change knowing that the main site IS NOT a WP site?

Comment: Never tried it before [This post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/non-wp-homepage-for-multisite) may be useful

Answer (score 2):

Yes yo can have multiple WordPress blogs on a single Domain.

Before install multiple WP review each answer posted by other. You can have better solution then installing multiple WP.